# Why is Spacy not executing the training pipeline even though the code runs without error?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am training a custom NER model with Spacy version 3.5.0 using some dummy data. My entire code and dummy data is given below. [This is exact same code give in the 2nd half of this link](https://github.com/dmoonat/Named-Entity-Recognition/blob/main/NER_with_spaCy.ipynb). The code is running fine, but it only executes until the **Initializing pipeline** step of the training and the **Training pipeline** is not executed.

Any idea why the training pipeline is not being executed?

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from tqdm import tqdm
from spacy.tokens import DocBin

train = [
          ("An average-sized strawberry has about 200 seeds on its outer surface and are quite edible.",{"entities":[(17,27,"Fruit")]}),
          ("The outer skin of Guava is bitter tasting and thick, dark green for raw fruits and as the fruit ripens, the bitterness subsides. ",{"entities":[(18,23,"Fruit")]}),
          ("Grapes are one of the most widely grown types of fruits in the world, chiefly for the making of different wines. ",{"entities":[(0,6,"Fruit")]}),
          ("Watermelon is composed of 92 percent water and significant amounts of Vitamins and antioxidants. ",{"entities":[(0,10,"Fruit")]}),
          ("Papaya fruits are usually cylindrical in shape and the size can go beyond 20 inches. ",{"entities":[(0,6,"Fruit")]}),
          ("Mango, the King of the fruits is a drupe fruit that grows in tropical regions. ",{"entities":[(0,5,"Fruit")]}),
          ("undefined",{"entities":[(0,6,"Fruit")]}),
          ("Oranges are great source of vitamin C",{"entities":[(0,7,"Fruit")]}),
          ("A apple a day keeps doctor away. ",{"entities":[(2,7,"Fruit")]})
        ]

db = DocBin() # create a DocBin object

for text, annot in tqdm(train): # data in previous format
    doc = nlp.make_doc(text) # create doc object from text
    ents = []
    for start, end, label in annot["entities"]: # add character indexes
        span = doc.char_span(start, end, label=label, alignment_mode="contract")
        if span is None:
            print("Skipping entity")
        else:
            ents.append(span)
    doc.ents = ents # label the text with the ents
    db.add(doc)

db.to_disk("./train.spacy") # save the docbin object

!python -m spacy init fill-config base_config.cfg config.cfg

!python -m spacy train config.cfg --output ./output --paths.train ./train.spacy --paths.dev ./train.spacy
```

**Expected output**

[image]

**Output I got**

[image]

Comment: Did you generate your base_config.cfg file from the spaCy quick start [page](https://spacy.io/usage/training#quickstart) using the same settings as the tutorial? Your output says that its using the GPU not CPU? After following the instructions I was able to train the model, albeit with spaCy 3.4.4 and Python 3.10.9

Comment: @KyleFHartzenberg Yes, I create exactly as mentioned in you link. I had selected NER, GPU and Accuracy for create the base_config.cfg

Comment: Try with CPU selected for your base_config.cfg file instead of the GPU and see if you get the same issue